# Post to an UpdateView without actually displaying the template for submission?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I've got a screen that displays objects a user has entered.

On this template form, there is a button next to the object - when the user clicks the button, it should update that object (mark it as 'done', a `Boolean`)

Can I post to this '`UpdateView`' without actually having to create a template for the `UpdateView`?

I suppose I could just post to a function-based view, but I'm trying to use ClassBasedViews to simplify things.

I've got a `CreateView` method that works without issue.

```
class TaskForm(forms.ModelForm):

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.task_location = kwargs.pop('task_location', None)
    super(TaskNeededForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['task'].queryset = Task.objects.filter(
        id__in=[task_item.task_id for task_item in
                TaskReference.objects.filter(
                    task_location_id=self.task_location,
                )
                ]
            )

class Meta:
    model = TaskNeed
    fields = ['task', 'task_percent', 'task_status']
```

My UpdateView looks like this:

```
class TaskNeededUpdate(SuccessMessageMixin, UpdateView):

model = TaskNeeded
fields = ['task', 'task_percent', 'task_status']
success_message = 'Task has been successfully updated.'
template_name = 'tasks/task_needed_form.html' #same form as CreateView

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.object = self.get_object()
    self.object.task_status = True
    self.object.save()
    return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

The form template looks like this:

```
        <form id="update-form" class="" action="" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <button class="btn bg-danger text-white" type="submit" name="button">Task Complete</button>
        </form>
```

The task `pk` is passed in via the URL:

```
path('<int:location_id>/task-needed/update/<int:pk>/', views.TaskNeededUpdate.as_view(), name='update_task'),
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. Yes, you can do this. What is doing the posting?

Comment: That form template is doing the posting (it's just a button so when it is submitted, we mark the task as done).

Comment: Now I'm more confused. Your question said you didn't want to create a template.

Comment: I'm getting some errors along the way - so the question was kind of multi-faceted in a "can you do this", "should you do this" and "does this look right?"

Comment: @DanielRoseman - sorry, there is a view that lists out the tasks. In that particular template - there is a button for each task - which is what triggers the post.